# Onkeypress canceling event javascript

Tags: onkeypress

I have a textbox that I would like to prevent the user from entering any letters in. They need to be able to enter numbers.

The textbox has an onkeypressed event already set, and I'm adding logic so that if the user enters a letter, nothing is shown.

Regardless of what I do (cancelbubble, stop propogation, return false), the letter is still getting entered in the text box. I've watched the debugger go over these and still the letter is being entered, its like it is taking place after the fact of the event.

Comment: You just _completely_ changed your question by adding that sentence.

Comment: yea sorry by letters I meant letters, they need to enter numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler hook you are looking for is [`onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onkeydown):

```
yourInput.onkeydown = function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which); // get the char
    return /[0-9]/.test(char);  //assert it's a number
}
```

### [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Rtwz/)

Returning false from an event handler attached directly (rather than attachEvent) cancels the event.

Comment: Blocks num pad as well, other than that pretty nice.

Comment: Ah ok, had a feeling it was the event. Thank you much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Actually once I got home to test onkeydown was doing the same thing, when I edited what was in the text box, it would still add the non-numeric character at the end.

Ended up using onkeyup, that appears to be far enough down the line that it will wipe out what is in the textbox.

I was really looking for the ajax filtered textbox functionality, but couldn't use that because we aren't using actual ajax controls in the application.

Comment: Your event is probably being remplaced somewhere in your code... try with addEventListener and attachEvent, with prevent default.

Comment: Yea I actually found I wasn't returning the function in the server side html. I had something like onkeypress="dothis()"...when I needed to do onkeypress="return dothis()".

Otherwise yea returning false in onkeypress will in fact prevent the letters from getting in the textbox. And onkeypress is really the only way to go because every other event can't figure out the proper charcode from the keycode, meaning you end up excluding the number pad as well.